# Using grep to find a binary pattern in a file

Tags: unix, grep, pattern-matching

Previously, I was able to find binary patterns in files using grep with

```
grep -a -b -o -P '\x01\x02\x03' <file>
```

By find I mean I was able to get the byte position of the pattern in the file. But when I tried doing this with the latest version of grep (v2.16) it no longer worked.

Specifically, I can manually verify that the pattern is present in the file but grep does not find it. Strangely, some patterns are found correctly but not others. For example, in a test file

```
000102030405060708090a0b0c0e0f
```

`'\x01\x02'` is found but not `'\x07\x08'`.

Any help in clarifying this behavior is highly appreciated.

**Update**: The above example does not show the described behavior. Here are the commands that exhibit the problem

```
printf `for (( x=0; x<256; x++ )); do printf "\x5cx%02x" $x; done` > test

for (( x=$((0x70)); x<$((0x8f)); x++ )); do
    p=`printf "\'\x5cx%02x\x5cx%02x\'" $x  $((x+1))`
    echo -n $p
    echo $p test | xargs grep -c -a -o -b -P | cut -d: -f1
done
```

The first line creates a file with all possible bytes from 0x00 to 0xff in a sequence. The second line counts the number of occurrences of pairs of consecutive byte values in the range 0x70 to 0x8f. The output I get is

```
   '\x70\x71'1
   '\x71\x72'1
   '\x72\x73'1
   '\x73\x74'1
   '\x74\x75'1
   '\x75\x76'1
   '\x76\x77'1
   '\x77\x78'1
   '\x78\x79'1
   '\x79\x7a'1
   '\x7a\x7b'1
   '\x7b\x7c'1
   '\x7c\x7d'1
   '\x7d\x7e'1
   '\x7e\x7f'1
   '\x7f\x80'0
   '\x80\x81'0
   '\x81\x82'0
   '\x82\x83'0
   '\x83\x84'0
   '\x84\x85'0
   '\x85\x86'0
   '\x86\x87'0
   '\x87\x88'0
   '\x88\x89'0
   '\x89\x8a'0
   '\x8a\x8b'0
   '\x8b\x8c'0
   '\x8c\x8d'0
   '\x8d\x8e'0
   '\x8e\x8f'0
```

**Update**: The same pattern occurs for single-byte patterns -- no bytes with value greater than 0x7f are found.

Comment: `\x07\x08` isn't in that sample data it goes from `\x07` to `\x09`.

Comment: Touche, that's a typo. It is in my actual test file.

Comment: Converted that sample input to a file with those bytes (`printf '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0e\x0f' > file`) and the grep worked for both '\x01\x02' and '\x07\x08' for me. Double check your file?

Comment: The original testing script had issues with unprintable characters (or something). It failed to report any patterns past '\x07\x08'. I updated the question with a fixed script.

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/deryni/a3659c2c677951e75993

Comment: Note that as of February 2015, the current version of GNU `grep` is 2.21, released in November 2014.  Version 2.16 is from January 2014.  I'm not convinced that has anything to do with it, but it might.

Comment: @EtanReisner What's your grep version?

Comment: 2.5.1 (its in the gist). So it broke at some point more recently then... and indeed it fails with 2.20 on another machine of mine.

Comment: Time for a bug report, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The results may depend on you current locale. To avoid this, use:

```
env LANG=LC_ALL grep -P "<binary pattern>" <file>
```

where `env LANG=LC_ALL` overrides your current locale to allow byte matching. Otherwise, patterns with non-ASCII "characters" such as `\xff` will not match.

For example, this fails to match because (at least in my case) the environment has `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`:

```
$ printf '\x41\xfe\n' | grep -P '\xfe'
```

when this succeeds:

```
$ printf '\x41\xfe\n' | env LANG=LC_ALL grep -P '\xfe'
A?
```